# quiero redireccionar a un controlador laravel desde un componente vuejs y pasarle un parametro

Tags: html, bootstrap, laravel-5, vue.js, programación-móvil

Muy buenas estoy en un componente vuejs y quiero llamar a un controlador laravel. Desde una vista laravel lo hacia asi:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{route('clientes.edit',$item->id)}}">Editar</a>
```

Donde `clientes` era mi controlador e `$item->id` era un valor que le pasaba al controlador.

Pero no puedo hacer lo mismo desde un componente vuejs.
Agradezco mucho de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿En el componente tienes esos datos? Me refiero a la url y al id.

Comment: Haber si me explico, estoy en un componente vuejs pero quiero pasarme a otra vista llamada desde otro controlador mediante un link pero no puedo , adicionalmente quisiera pasarle un parametro, trabajando solo en laravel me funcionaba como muestro en el ejemplo pero desde el componente vue no